# Getting QGIS print composer error due to JavaScript problem?

Tags: qgis, javascript, print-composer, printing

I've been experiencing a problem with the QGIS print composer. I am working on a Linux Ubuntu platform (Release 12.04 (precise) 64-bit) and I am using QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour.

I need to export a number of maps I have recently created, in either JPG or PDF format (in both 300 and 600 dpi), however, while I am trying to export them using the QGIS print composer the whole system crashes and shuts down immediately!

A pop out window appears and the the error it gives me is the following:

**Java script problem:
The script on this page appears to have a problem. Do you want to stop the script?**

Whenever I choose -NO- (Not to stop the script) nothing is functioning, unless I choose the option -YES- (To stop the script) so apparently my QGIS project/ workspace immediately shuts down!

Could you give me any hints on how I could fix this problem?

I have already tried to export my maps using much lower dpi (100 and 150, etc.) but unfortunately it still gives me this error (!)

I have already checked previous posts/ replies and I have to mention that I have checked my labelling already. In QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour there is no 'old' and 'new' labelling. I do use however transparency and shadow in my labels.

---

I just figured out what the problem is! I've been using as background the Google Satellite OpenLayers Plugin, which uses the EPSG code:3857. My population density raster layer is in WGS84, and I have set the CRS of my QGIS Project (from the Project Properties) to be WGS84. So when I was trying to export it using the Print Composer my whole system was crashing!

What I still have to figure out though is how to make my population density raster look better in terms or pixelization. When I set my Project's CRS as WGS84 (EPSG:4326) my raster image looks absolutely fine but crashes if I try to export it as PDF/JPG, on the other hand if I set the CRS of my project as WGS84 Pseudo Mercator (EPSG:3857), my raster seems to pixelate when I make it large.

Any ideas on how to visualise it properly?

Comment: It appears that you found your own answer to your original question, and are now trying to answer a follow on question.  With no answers or comments in 5.5 years, if you still seek an answer I think you should heavily revise your question to focus it only on whatever the remaining issue is.